# Redis кэширование

Tags: php, база-данных, веб-программирование, кэширование, redis

Redis кэширование - очень популярная вещь. Пытался найти в интернете - [кэширование redis](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D0%BA%D1%8D%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20redis&newwindow=1&sxsrf=ALiCzsaMOaDL6TjqmK9nW8zuQM5w8OucmA%3A1662306153187&ei=accUY7SHC8uxrgTrsJqwAQ&ved=0ahUKEwj035L-vPv5AhXLmIsKHWuYBhYQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=%D0%BA%D1%8D%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20redis&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBAgjECcyBAgjECc6CggAEEcQ1gQQsAM6BggAEB4QFkoECEEYAEoECEYYAFDFCVijDGCjFWgCcAF4AIABfogB-QGSAQMwLjKYAQCgAQHIAQjAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz). Но не нашел примеры кода (один только [Redis на практических примерах](https://habr.com/ru/company/manychat/blog/507136/)). Киньте ссылки на примеры кода redis кэширования (также укажите запросы для загугливания, чтоб я понимал, почему я не нашел).

Comment: Что вы хотите в примерах увидеть?... для него там пару методов достаточно `$redis->get('key')` и `$redis->set('key', $value)`... принцип работы с кешем везде один и тот же `if(кеш_не_найден){ вычисляемЗначение(); кладёмВКеш();} else { получаемИхКеша();}`

Comment: @МихаилРебров а какие данные должны попадать в кэш (которые `кладемВКеш();`)?

Comment: Вы до этого с кешированием работали?

Comment: @МихаилРебров Только кэш браузера очищал. Как правило там лежали картинки, видео, некоторые html страницы. Какие условия попадания в кэш?

Comment: в таком случае вам сначала разобраться в теме кеширования.

Comment: `а какие данные должны попадать в кэш`... какие решили - те и попадут.. что стоит класть в кеш, а что нет - уже другой вопрос.